# Incorrect date time format in update statement

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MySQL database. I have an update statement and I am trying to update my data table from ASP.NET SQL query.

```
UPDATE customer_request 
SET Issue = 'Broken_Wire', 
FixedDate = '2015-05-17 14:05:46' 
WHERE CustReqID = 102 
AND ErrorReportedDate = STR_TO_DATE('5/17/2015 11:42:26 AM','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

I get this error:

> Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '5/17/2015 11:42:26 AM' for function str_to_date

What is incorrect in my query?

Answer (score 1):

This part of your where clause doesn't correctly set the format of your date

```
  STR_TO_DATE('5/17/2015 11:42:26 AM','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

instead you probably want

```
  STR_TO_DATE('5/17/2015 11:42:26 AM','%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

where

```
 %e  = Day of the month without leading zero e.g., 1,2,…31 
 %c  = Month in numeric e.g., 1, 2, 3…12
 %Y  = Four digits year e.g., 2000, 2001
 %H  = Hour with 24-hour format with leading zero e.g., 00..23
 %i  = Minutes with leading zero e.g., 00, 01,…59
 %S or %s = Seconds with leading zero 00,01,…59
```

You could read about the [DATE_FORMAT specifiers here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_format/)

Comment: tried using the format but still gives the same error

Comment: Removed the AM/PM specs, changed %m in %c and tried in MySql Workbench. It seems to work